# Oracle SQL formatting

Tags: oracle

I Have a query to get bill data, grouped by the calendar year and the week of the year. I want to have the evolution of bills in total. So not only the number of bills of 1 week but from the beginning until the week. I have following query

```
SELECT DD.CAL_YEAR, DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR AS "Date by week", SUM(DISTINCT FAB.ID) OVER ( ORDER BY DD.CAL_YEAR, DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS "Number of bills"
    FROM BILLS_TABLE FAB
    JOIN DIM_DATE DD ON FAB.BALANCE_DATE_ID = DD.ID
    GROUP BY  DD.CAL_YEAR,DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR;
```

But when I execute this query I get following exception:

> Error: ORA-30487: ORDER BY not allowed here
>
> SQLState:  99999 ErrorCode: 30487

The order by clause is needed for the OVER function, so what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is really the use of `distinct` inside `sum`.

Because you have the `order by` clause, that means you are doing a cumulative sum.  Performing a `distinct` in that case doesn't really make any sense.  That's what the error is actually trying to tell you.

The documentation for the [SUM analytic function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions182.htm#SQLRF06115) mentions this:

> If you specify `DISTINCT`, then you can specify only the `query_partition_clause` of the `analytic_clause`. The `order_by_clause` and `windowing_clause` are not allowed.

Comment: Ok and when I drop the distinct I get another Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: An analytic function doesn't work the same way as a normal aggregate function.  Your analytic function can only refer to columns in your `group by` clause.